# convert curl call into java urlconnection call

Tags: java, curl, rabbitmq, trace

I have curl command:

```
curl -i -u guest:guest -H "content-type:application/json"
-XPUT \ http://localhost:15672/api/traces/%2f/my-trace \
-d'{"format":"text","pattern":"#"}'
```

And I want to create HTTP Request in Java API which will do the same thing. This curl command can be found in this [README](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-tracing/blob/master/README). It is used to start recording log on RabbitMQ. Response is not important.

For now I created something like this (I've deleted less important lines i.e. with catching exception etc.), but unfortunately it doesn't work:

```
url = new URL("http://localhost:15672/api/traces/%2f/my-trace");
uc = url.openConnection();

uc.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
uc.setRequestProperty("format","json");
uc.setRequestProperty("pattern","#")
String userpass = "guest:guest";
String basicAuth = "Basic " + javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(userpass.getBytes());
uc.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", basicAuth);
```

[ENTIRE CODE](http://pastebin.com/RFARk3jA)

Comment: Do you get any error? What exactly do you mean by "it doesn't work"?

Comment: This should create log file which can be seen in RabbitMQ management page, but it is not created.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is final solution:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.Proxy;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

public class Curl {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {

    String url = "http://127.0.0.1:15672/api/traces/%2f/trololo";

    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    conn.setDoOutput(true);

    conn.setRequestMethod("PUT");

    String userpass = "user" + ":" + "pass";
    String basicAuth = "Basic " + javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(userpass.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    conn.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", basicAuth);

    String data =  "{\"format\":\"json\",\"pattern\":\"#\"}";
    OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
    out.write(data);
    out.close();

    new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());   

    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

two problems that i can see:

- you aren't setting the request method, in your curl example it is "PUT"
- the '-d' data should be the request *body*, not request parameters (i.e. you should be writing that string to the request OutputStream)

also, when you do `userpass.getBytes()` you are getting the bytes using the default platform character encoding.  this may or may not be the encoding that you desire.  better to use an explicit character encoding (presumably the one the server is expecting).

Comment: I tried to do this things, but it still doesn't work. Here's new code: http://pastebin.com/Ziqx3Z68

Comment: @user2219448 - it's generally easiest to update your answer or create a new question.  that said, you should probably set the method _after_ you set doOutput.  also, you should _not_ be url encoding the body content.  an easy way to debug something like this is to use an http proxy like charles proxy to examine the requests on the wire and see how your output differs from the curl output.

Comment: Thank you for your help, debugging with charles proxy was also helpful. Cheers. (can't give +1, not enough reputation..)