# How does a curl command translate to Java code?

Tags: java, curl

I was able to locate some solutions, but none have worked for me. I am new to Java and have had no success so far with curl in Java.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -o output.json --data-binary @input.json http://webaddress.com
```

The JSON file.

```
{
   "firstNumber": "00",
   "secondNumber": "12",
   "Type": "MyType",
   "data": [0,0,0,0,0]
}
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean how does it translate?

Comment: Are you asking how to launch curl from java or how to replicate the functionality of curl in java?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert curl call into java urlconnection call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15684846/convert-curl-call-into-java-urlconnection-call)

Comment: I am asking how to replicate the actions of that curl command using Java code.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to invoke the command from java:

```
Process proc = 
    run.exec(new String[] {
     "/bin/sh", 
     "-c",
     "curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -o output.json --data-binary @input.json http://webaddress.com"
    });
```

`/bin/sh` is the location of your shell. `-c` executes the commands after.

Of course, move your command to some kind of string constant and also you may extract a utility method for executing commands, if your shell path will remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

I've had good experience with Spring's RestTemplate, here's a sample:

```
JSONObject request = new JSONObject();
request.put("attribute1", "value");
request.put("attribute2", "value2");

RestTemplate restTemplate=new RestTemplate();
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(request.toString(), headers);

ResponseEntity<String> loginResponse = restTemplate.exchange(urlString, HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, this look like a string is being sent. How would i change this to use the --data-binary from the curl command.

Comment: you would read the file and convert it to String if the file contains raw Json.