# How to translate curl commands in to java code?

Tags: java, rest, curl

I have two curl commands to execute. The second command needs to "remember" the login made by the first one. I do not know about curl but I think the `--cookie` parameter is doing the job.

well, curl is not for me. I need to do the same in Java but I can't rely in the environment ( cannot invoke `/bin/sh -c curl` ).

How can I do the same "login and still logged in" method in Java?

Already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40771121/how-does-a-curl-command-translate-to-java-code) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15684846/convert-curl-call-into-java-urlconnection-call) but both are "login every time will use".

```
curl -k -d "email=some@email.com&password=mysecret" -X POST 'https://some.site.com/index.php?some=parameter' --cookie "cookies.txt" --cookie-jar "cookies.txt"

curl -k "https://some.site.com/index.php?some=parameter" --cookie "cookies.txt" --cookie-jar "cookies.txt" --output test.tif
```

Comment: did you try using `HttpContext` class as in 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166129/apache-httpclient-4-0-3-how-do-i-set-cookie-with-sessionid-for-post-request

Comment: you basically need content of `cookies.txt` file and use it to `httppost.setHeader`
for Apache Client>=4.5 you need to set domain as well `cookie.setDomain(".domain.com");
cookie.setAttribute(ClientCookie.DOMAIN_ATTR, "true");`.

Comment: Nice. I Will give a try.

Comment: Am I asking too much if you answer my question with a functional snipet using my examples?